# I want to generate 3000 above pdf files from prestashop back end

Tags: pdf, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.7

I am  using tcpdf pdf generator for generating  Eticket, as same as the prestahsop generates the pdf files for invoices , I am trying to generate the pdf files of tickets( I am selling tickets online) ,3000 tickets  daily I need to print from the back end how to do this 3000 tickets printing ??I mean how to generate 3000 tickets of pdf  in one click ?
Also I need to validate the printing whether 3000 pdf for the corresponding ticket was generated or not how to do this validation(count validation).

```
public function generatePDF($object, $template)
{
    switch($template) {
        case PDF::TEMPLATE_ETICKET:
            $format = 'JIS_B5'; // Replace with your desired size for Back office Eticket
            break;
        default:
            $format = 'A4'; // Replace with normal size
    }
    $pdf = new PDF($object, $template, Context::getContext()->smarty,'P', $format);
    $pdf = $pdf->render(false);


    return true;
}
```

Comment: This will take a hell of a lot of time. You're better off generating tickets once an order is validated rather than generating them all at once.

Comment: End  of the day  say at  a particular time i need  to generate the tickets to put that tickets half portion in raffle drum  manually